# Erro ao tentar enviar e-mail em massa

Tags: php, laravel, email

Tenho um sistema em laravel e nele é realizado disparos de e-mails em massa constantemente. Utilizo o SMTP LocaWeb para enviar. Só que estou tendo muitos erros do mesmo tipo.

```
Swift_TransportException: Connection to ssl://smtplw.com.br:465 Timed Out in
```

Já contactei a locaweb, mas eles afirmaram que o erro não é com o servidor SMTP.

Não há, aparentemente, nenhum erro em minha aplicação.

Comment: Tem certeza que esse é o servidor SMTP da Locaweb? Eu uso outro: email-ssl.com.br

Comment: Sim! É um dos servidores.

Comment: Sugiro que pare o Swift_Transport, depois inicie explicitamente, antes de enviar a segunda mensagem. Meu pensamento é que a conexão está sendo mantida por muito tempo (sem nenhuma atividade), causando um Time Out.